# Azure Service Bus Queue Triggered Function not getting invoked

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have written a .Net Core 6 code which sends message to a Service Bus Queue which in turn triggers a Function(SB Queue triggered) where I intend to do further processing of the received data. Although the messages gets sent to the queue, the Function doesn't get triggered and the messages end up in the Dead Letter Queue.

Below is my Function code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyWebApp.Domain.Entities;
using MyWebApp.Domain.Repositories.Interface;

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ITaskRepository _taskRepository;

        public Function1(ITaskRepository taskRepository)
        {
            _taskRepository = taskRepository;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mysbqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] TaskModel myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                await _taskRepository.UpdateTask(myQueueItem);
                log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, I've added the `ServiceBusConnectionString`in the function app `local.settings.json` as well as in the configuration section of the Function App in the Azure portal but it doesn't help. I can't debug the Function App in my my local as well, as it says - `The breakpoint will not currently e hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.`

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The behavior where you don't see your code invoked but messages are ending up in dead letter sounds like there's a serialization/binding issue.   Are you using the Functions in-process model?  If not, you can't bind to a custom model type.  Assuming in-proc, what happens if you change the binding from `TaskModel` to `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

If the messages are going to the dead lead, the function is getting triggered, but there is some error in the logic which after some attempts is moving the message to dead letter queue.

I recommend you instrument the function and monitor through Application Insights / Log Stream to figure out where/what is the problem.